# Why qt creates this folder

Tags: qt

I've created qt project called calculator so the file path on my disc is:

```
C:\excercizes\QT_projects\calculator
```

but qt created another extra directory next to it, which looks like:

```
C:\excercizes\QT_projects\Calculator-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug
```

What for is this directory? I see inside it two folders called debug and release but even when I build this project in release mode nothing is placed there, instead folders debug and release inside the first directory mentioned are used.
Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's shadow building. You can desactivate that if you want.

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-glossary.html#glossary-shadow-build